# Wird das Genitiv-s bei feststehenden Ausdrücken / Codenamen gesetzt?

Tags: expression, genitive, inflection, brand-name

Ich verfasse einen Text zu einer Aktion mit dem Codenamen *Projekt Omen*. Es handelt sich also um einen feststehenden Ausdruck aus zwei Wörtern, nicht nur um ein Projekt mit dem Namen *Omen*.

Welche der folgenden Flexionen ist nun richtig?

> der Erfolg des Projekt Omen
>
> der Erfolg des Projekts Omen
>
> der Erfolg des Projekt Omens

Comment: Kann man auch Omenprojekt sagen? Ich arbeite am Omenprojekt?

Comment: Wie gut, dass man mittlerweile den Dativ nehmen darf (*Der Erfolg von "Projekt Omen"*) ;)

Comment: Die ursprüngliche Frage wird leider nicht beantwortet. Wie werden feststehende Ausdrücke gebeugt? "Der Wert des Grund und Bodens" wird von Word angemeckert, aber "Der Wert des Grunds und Bodens" klingt bescheuert. Wie soll Word auch erkennen dass es ein einziger Begriff ist? Gibt es unsichtbare Bindestriche?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

»Projekt Omen« ist kein feststehender Begriff, jedenfalls nicht fester als »Land Salzburg«, »Berg Sinai« oder »Bruder Jakob«. Diese Begriffe sind nach folgendem Schema aufgebaut:

> <*Kategorie*> <*Name*>

Wenn ein solcher Ausdruck im Genitiv verwendet wird, wird nur die Kategorie gebeugt:

> der Erfolg des Projekts Omen
>   die Regierung des Landes Salzburg
>   der Gipfel des Berges Sinai
>   die Kutte des Bruders Jakob

Ohne die Kategorie wird der Name gebeugt:

> der Erfolg Omens
>   die Regierung Salzburgs
>   der Gipfel Sinais
>   die Kutte Jakobs